# Email with cc in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

I need to send email with cc to customers. But when I set cc and send the mail receiver got mail as 'to' and not showing the cc people. Is there any way to fix that in odoo 10?

Comment: consider providing an actual piece of code

Comment: Do you want this in code related?@Ridma Gimhani

Comment: @Naveen Yes.. If you can... Please

Comment: It is very simple, ok i ll send you the code@RidmaGimhani

Comment: sorry for the delay@RidmaGimhani

Answer (score 1):

In xml:

```
<!--Email template -->
<record id="example_email_template" model="mail.template">
    <field name="name">Vendor address : Changed</field>
    <field name="email_from">${object.company_id and object.company_id.email or
        ''}
    </field>
    <field name="subject">Address Changed for ${object.name}</field>
    <field name="email_to">person@mail.com
    </field>
    <field name="email_cc">person@mail.com</field>
    <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner" />
    <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
    <field name="body_html">
        <![CDATA[
        Updated by ${(object.creating_user_id.name)}<br/>
        IP Address:${(object.ip_address or '')}<br/>
            <p>Updated Address:</p></br>
            ${(object.street or '')}<br/>
            ${(object.street2 or '')}<br/>
            ${(object.city or '')}<br/>
            ${(object.state_id.name or '')}<br/>
            ${(object.zip or '')}<br/>
            ${(object.country_id.name or '')}
    ]]>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: in this case ,If I use an email template, our customers can't see the other persons in CC. did you have any solution for that

Comment: might be some group problem@RidmaGimhani

Comment: It will be easy to fix, take a look at the security groups you have given and all

Comment: I didn't set any security for mail.It is default

Comment: I need to display the people who got the same mail as cc or inside the body

Comment: Did you completed your task?@RidmaGimhani

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but not give 100% solution for the above question. Still I am trying..
first Inherit mail.mail and add following code to that

```
@api.model
def send_get_mail_cc(self):
    #set the email field with all the recipients
    for mail_id in self.ids:
        mail = self.browse(mail_id)
        email_cc = []
        for partner in mail.recipient_ids:
           email_cc.append(partner.email)
    return email_cc
```

Then replace 'def send_get_email_dict' with this

```
@api.multi
def send_get_email_dict(self, partner=None):

    self.ensure_one()
    body = self.send_get_mail_body(partner=partner)
    body_alternative = tools.html2plaintext(body)
    res = {
        'body': body,
        'body_alternative': body_alternative,
        'email_to': self.send_get_mail_to(partner=partner),
        'email_cc': self.send_get_mail_cc(),
    }
    return res
```

then replace the 'email_cc=tools.email_split(mail.email_cc),' which is inside the 'def send' method by

```
email_cc=email.get('email_cc'),
```

then all mail address which send the mail will show under cc in your mail(If anyone can solve that one,please correct my answer. I also trying)

Comment: Good try@Ridma Gimhani

Comment: Have you achieved on what you need ?

Comment: No, here not give the thing what I need .. Finally I create my own method and from that I create a mail. I'll post my answer here.

Comment: @Naveen in odoo default they took the all template mail addresses to the recipient ids field.you can understand the process by looking @ the 'mail-->models-->mail_template.py'. there you can see the method called  "def generate_recipients". By referring that you can understand what happen when we create the mail using a template

Answer (score 1):

Here what I need is when change the state to 'closed' by drag and dropping,email should send the users. Here what I did.

```
@api.constrains('stage_id')
def onchange_stage_id(self):
     if self.stage_id:
         stage_name= self.stage_id.name
         so_no = self.env['sale.order'].search([('id', '=',self.so_no.id)]).name
         task_no = self.task_no
         subject_str= "Closed Task Details of "+task_no
         msg = MIMEMultipart()
         body_str ="""\
                    <html>
                      <head></head>
                      <body>
                        <p>Dear,<br>
                           Here is the closed task with reference to:"""+task_no +""". <br>
                           Closed under the sales order:"""+so_no +""".
                        </p>
                      </body>
                    </html>
                    """
         mail_server=self.env['ir.mail_server'].search([('name', '=',"Gmail Outgoing Server")]).id
         if stage_name == "Closed":
             mail=self.env['mail.mail'].create({
                 'email_to':"example1@gmail.com,example2@gmail.com,example3@gmail.com",
                 'email_cc':"example4@gmail.com,example5@gmail.com@gmail.com,example6@gmail.com@gmail.com",
                 'mail_server_id':mail_server,
                 'body_html':body_str,
                 'subject':subject_str,

             })
             mail.send()
```

Here I add the mail address manually

Comment: Superb@RidmaGImhani

Comment: Post any new things you do on odoo here, if you do@RidmaGimhani

Comment: @Naveen sure. I will